# vue js validation error where trying to push the error code in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i declared the error in the `data()` as `listErrors = []`

now in my validation function, i am checking lie this

```
let listErrors = []

if (this.floor == '') {
                        listErrors.push({ 'name': 'Floor', value: 'required' });        
                    }

if (this.street == '') {
                        listErrors.push({ 'name': 'Street', value: 'required' });        
                    }

if (this.address == '') {
                        listErrors.push({ 'Address': 'Floor', value: 'required' });        
                    }
```

but i did a console.log, but i am always getting is empty

I had posted the code above

Comment: Hi, can you add more details? which value are you trying to log?

Comment: i am just trying to get the errors in array as arrayofobjects so i can loop over them an display hem

Comment: This part of the code looks ok, the problem must be elsewhere, can you add the entire code and where you are trying to console.log?

Comment: console.log is just after the if this.address, so i see the values are going in, but it is just showing me -observer

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as described in the stackoverflow help. Otherwise it's not possible to help you here, as only you know, where you do the logging and this is important to know in order to help you out here.